# How to properly transfer a File Array to another activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm tryng to transfer a Array from an activity to another in order to use it in that new activity, strings are really easy but file arrays give errors.

I have tried to transfer it as a String array or just as a string but doesn't do anything.

First activity(with a string example that works):

```
public static final ArrayList<File> EXTRA_keyfiles = new ArrayList<File>();
public static final String EXTRA_keynames = "";
```

```
File key = new File(DirPath, fileName);
// add files to the array and strings to fileNames
Intent intent = new Intent(this, StealthService.class);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_keynames, fileNames);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_keyfiles, keyFiles);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity(tried to transfer as a string array):

```
ArrayList<String> names = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_keynames);
        ArrayList<String> files = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_keyfiles);
```

How can i properly transfer the Array

Answer (score 0):

Use `putStringArrayListExtra` instead of `putExtra` in the first activity.

Comment: It gives error because your are tryng to link a file array to a string array `putStringArrayListExtra
(java.lang.String,
java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>)
in Intent cannot be applied
to
(java.util.ArrayList<java.io.File>,
java.util.ArrayList<java.io.File>)`